# Visual Studio 11 Installation Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting an error while trying to install Visual Studio 11:

The log file shows:

> [13F0:1D38][2012-04-23T12:53:01]: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package
>   (vs_professionalcore) failed: Error Message Id: 1316 ErrorMessage:
>   Error 1316.A network error occurred while attempting to read from the
>   file: C:\Windows\Installer\vs_professionalcore.msi

I've tried the Professional and the Ultimate versions and both with the ISO and Web Installer. I always get the same error.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with Visual Studio 2013 Premium. I simply downloaded the iso from http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads and then copied the vs_professionalcore.msi and associated cab files into C:\Windows\Installer\ . After that, performing Uninstall worked successfully.

For Visual Studio 2013 the msi and cab files were in:
 IsoRoot\packages\professionalcore\Setup

Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Is your computer on a domain?  It might be the problem in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/b5f6849f-843f-494d-a1dd-fdf36657bcab .

Here is what that thread suggests, no idea if its the same problem, though:

---

**WORKAROUND:** 
After installing Windows 8 and VS 2011 with a local account or Live ID, connect your computer to a direct hard-wired internet  connection (not through LAN of your company). Run VS 2011 and get your developer license for this computer. Then plug off your computer from the internet connection and instead plug in the network cable of your company. Provide your network credentials and proxy info when you want to connect to internet. The advantage now is that you can also connect to web services on your network that are behind the DMZ and the designer works too :)